# Find the area of the region bounded by the graphs of: $x^2+z^2=25$, $z \geq 0$, $y=0$ and $y=2z$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, area

Find the area of the region bounded by the graphs of:
$x^2+z^2=25$, $z \geq 0$, $y=0$ and $y=2z$.

I've drawn the graphs but I'm unsure how to approach the problem. I'm supposed to use double integrals but I don't know how to set that up.

[image]

Comment: Is it surface area or volume? If area, do you understand the region you have to find surface area of? Also, is your problem only finding the bounds?

Comment: its the area and I dont see or understand the surface.

Comment: While double integrals can be used to calculate areas, their use is not automatic. Areas are usually calculated using surface integrals. What kind of technique are you expected to use?

Comment: I do not know what you are struggling with so it is difficult to help. If you posted more context to your question, what techniques you are familiar with to find surface area and why you are not able to apply here then I can help. The surface area is union of a semi-circle in xz plane ($y = 0$), cylinder's lateral surface between $y=0$ and $y = 2z, z \geq 0$ and part of the surface of the plane $y = 2z$ intersected by cylinder at $y=0$.

Comment: I can't really visualize the lateral area. I don't know that I should work. I understand the portion between $y = 0$ with $y = 2z$, but the one that corresponds to $z\geq 0$ I cannot understand. I would greatly appreciate a drawing or a graphic to view.

Comment: Now I can see, butI need help to parameterize the surface of the cylinder that lies between the two planes